# C# collections and comparison of items in them

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, interface, comparison

I am a beginner at .NET and C# programming and therefore my questions may be a little obscured. But nevertheless I try to ask for help this community.

I am programming a circular linked list using [this article](http://navaneethkn.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/circular-linked-list/) as help. I understand the main idea, but few things are incomprehensible for me.

1. An author says in the beginning, that our list must "maintain collection semantics". Couldn't you explain, what is this collection semantics? As I understand, it is a set of some interfaces that must be implemented in our class. Is it true? And if yes – what exactly must we maintain in this class and why? Are these two interfaces in the article (ICollection, IEnumerable) enough, or these are only the most necessary ones?
2. In a function that searches for a node with a given value

   ```
   public Node<T> Find(T item)
   {
       Node<T> node = FindNode(head, item);
       return node;
   }

   Node<T> FindNode(Node<T> node, T valueToCompare)
   {
       Node<T> result = null;
       if (comparer.Equals(node.Value, valueToCompare))
           result = node;
       else if (result == null && node.Next != head)
           result = FindNode(node.Next, valueToCompare);
       return result;
   }
   ```

   an author uses an `IEqualityComparer<T> comparer` object, which is initialized with a property `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` in one of constructors. Can you please explain me an idea of using of these interface (`IEqualityComparer<T>`) and class (`EqualityComparer<T>`) here? I had read MSDN, but I didn't understand the principles of working and using of them.

If my questions are too general, couldn't you suggest me some resources I might look through to find answers myself and streamline concepts in my mind?

Comment: Please ask one question per post... It is very hard to answer 2 very different questions with one concrete answer.

Comment: If I were you I'd drop the first, second, and final paragraphs. They don't add to the question greatly. Then post 1. & 2. as separate questions - and add back in the fact that you're writing a circular linked list.

Comment: Damn, I've almost finished writing a detailed answer... That's frustrating. It's not too broad in my opinion overall even if it could be split in half.

Comment: Done. Separate question about semantics is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202036/what-is-a-collection-semantics-in-net). Either one will be in 90 minutes. @Enigmativity

Comment: Either question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202921/using-of-iequalitycomparert-interface-and-equalitycomparert-class-in-c-sharp).