# What is collection semantics (in .NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, interface, semantics

I need to maintain collection semantics in my own class. Couldn't you explain, what is the collection semantics? As I understand, it is a set of some interfaces that must be implemented in a class. Is it true? And if yes – **what** exactly must I implement in the class and **why**? Are these two interfaces – ICollection and IEnumerable – enough, or these are only the most necessary ones?

I am programming a circular linked list using [this article](http://navaneethkn.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/circular-linked-list/) as help.

Comment: The linked article already implements ICollection.

Comment: Yes, I know. And it was a little confusing for me. @HenkHolterman

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many collection types in .NET, and they all share some common behavior, for instance:

- You can enumerate them using `foreach`
- They have a `Count` property
- You can add items using the `Add` method
- etc...

This behavior is expected from a collection type, and you guessed it right: it's all in the `ICollection<T>` interface. Let's take a look at the interface hierarchy:

- `IEnumerable<T>` allows your class to be enumerated with `foreach`
- `ICollection<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>` that represents a collection:

  - it allows to retrieve the item `Count`
  - you *possibly* can `Add`/`Remove`/`Clear` items from the collection
  - a collection could be read only, in that case `IsReadOnly` should return `true`
  - There's a couple other helper methods too: `Contains`/`CopyTo`.
- `IList<T>` is an `ICollection<T>` that allows items to be accessed by index.

  - It adds an indexer
  - some index-related functions: `Insert`/`RemoveAt`
  - `IndexOf`

Which interface you should implement is a matter of **semantics**:

**`IEnumerable<T>`** is just an enumerable *sequence*. It should only be enumerated once by consuming code, because you never know how it may behave on multiple enumerations. Tools like ReSharper will even emit warnings if you enumerate an `IEnumerable<T>` multiple times.
Sure, most of the time you can safely enumerate it multiple times but there are times when you shouldn't. For instance, an enumeration could execute a SQL query (think Linq-to-SQL for instance).

You implement an `IEnumerable<T>` by defining one function: `GetEnumerator` which returns en `IEnumerator<T>`. An enumerator is an object that is a kind of pointer to a current element in your sequence. It can return this `Current` value, and it can move to the next element with `MoveNext`. It's also disposable (and it's disposed at the end of the enumeration by `foreach`).

Let's decompose a `foreach` loop:

```
IEnumerable<T> sequence = ... // Whatever
foreach (T item in sequence)
    DoSomething(item);
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
IEnumerator<T> enumerator = null;
try
{
    enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        T item = enumerator.Current;
        DoSomething(item);
    }
}
finally
{
    if (enumerator != null)
        enumerator.Dispose();
}
```

For the record, implementing `IEnumerable` is not strictly required to make a class usable with a `foreach`. Duck typing is sufficient here but I'm digressing way too much.

And of course you can implement the pattern easily with the `yield` keyword:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetAnswer()
{
    yield return 42;
}
```

This will create a private class which will implement `IEnumerable<int>` for you so you don't have to.

**`ICollection<T>`** represents a collection, which is safely enumerable multiple times. But you don't really know what kind of collection it it. It could be a set, a list, a dictionary, whatever.

This is the collection semantics.

Some examples:

- `T[]` - it implements `ICollection<T>` even if you can't `Add`/`Remove`
- `List<T>`
- `HashSet<T>` - a good example of a collection but not a list
- `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` - yes, that's an `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`
- `LinkedList<T>`
- `ObservableCollection<T>`

**`IList<T>`** lets you know the collection is of the kind that lets you access elements by index easily (that is in *O(1)* time).

This is not the case for your circular linked list, as not only it would need *O(n)* time, but there's no meaningful index in the first place.

Some examples:

- `T[]`
- `List<T>`
- `ObservableCollection<T>`

Notice that `HashSet<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are no longer in the list for instance. These are not lists. `LinkedList<T>` is semantically a list, but it doesn't offer access by index in *O(1)* time (it requires *O(n)*).

I should mention there are read only equivalents that made in into .NET 4.5: `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>`, `IReadOnlyList<out T>`. These are nice for the covariance they provide.

Comment: Thank you very much for your exhaustive explanation! Now thoughts are clearer in my mind.