# LinQ in C#, why does query sentence must convert to tolist()?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    private static List<Member> members = new List<Member>
    {
        new Member() {m_FirstName = "Chiristopher", m_LastName="Harrison"},
        new Member() {m_FirstName = "Jeremy", m_LastName =  "Foster"},
        new Member() {m_FirstName = "Stacey", m_LastName = "Mulcahy"}
    };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = (from m in members
                     where m.m_LastName.Length > 6
                     select m);


        Console.WriteLine("** First Execution **");

        foreach(var member in result)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(member);
        }

        members.Add(new Member() { m_FirstName = "Rian", m_LastName = "ThyTuhfadsl" });

        Console.WriteLine("** Second Execution **");

        foreach (var member in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(member);
        }
    }
}
```

When I built it:
Console:
** First Execution **
Chiristopher  Harrison
Stacey Mulcahy
** Sencond Execution **
Chiristopher  Harrison
Stacey Mulcahy
Rian ThyTuhfadsl

if I debug, result variable has 3 values at the first, but it just print two values.  Why?

and at the second, is four values. Although, I dont retype any code

if I type

```
var result = (from m in members
                     where m.m_LastName.Length > 6
                     select m).toList();
```

is only two values in any cases.

Comment: Linq has deffered execution so you query executes only in materialization places such as `foreach` cycle or `ToList()` function

Comment: @JustinHarvey, [try yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JpTcdm). Correct answer was already given by Selman22.

Comment: @Sinatr the question is valid and not related to the answer. Yes, LINQ returns an enumerator but what the OP describes can only happen if he steps in the code with a watch on `result` and checks the `Results` shown in the watch window at the wrong moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`if I debug, result variable has 3 values at the first,`*

In addition to what others have stated and if I  understand your issue correctly the 3 values you are speaking about the result refers to `source` property which is not materialized yet because it's just an instance of the

```
  private class WhereListIterator<TSource> : Enumerable.Iterator<TSource>
    {
      private List<TSource> source;
      private Func<TSource, bool> predicate;
      private List<TSource>.Enumerator enumerator;
```

so your code is correct

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because linq queries are lazily evaluated. Most of the  linq query methods returns an `Iterator` variable.That iterator is only executed when you iterate over using `foreach` of call some methods like `ToArray` or `ToList` that iterates over the results and add them into list.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of 'lazy execution', you can search it on line.

The query is not executed until needed. (Only when you iterate it).

The '.tolist()' command force the execution of the query.

Answer (score 1):

A linq query may be of several types, as defined in .NET:

- `IEnumerable<T>` for linq-to-objects
- `IQueryable<T>` for linq-to-sql
- `ParallelQuery<T>` for PLINQ
- and so on...

In your case, you're using linq-to-objects, so the `result` variable is of type `IEnumerable<Member>`. This is defined as an enumerable sequence, which is not necessarily materialized until you actually enumerate it. And this is what happens here. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202545/3764814) where I elaborate a bit more about enumerables.

We say the query is lazily evaluated. The second time you enumerate it, it is re-evaluated. If you call `.ToList()` you will materialize the query only once and get a list, which will yield the same result on both enumerations.

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with the lazy evaluation of linq queries. If you write `ToList()` after a linq query it gets immediatly evaluated and materialized. If you don't write `ToList()` the query is evaluated only when it is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code sample, you enumerate the original list twice.

But when you replace the LINQ query by your last code sample, you make a copy of the original sequence.
The LINQ method [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) makes a copy of the sequence into a `List<T>` instance.
So in this case, you would enumerate the copy of the sequence twice, while having changed the original list in between.