# Determine if a Type is a Generic List of Enum Types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, enums

I have the need to determine if a given type if a generic list of enum types.

I came up with the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    TestIfListOfEnum(typeof(int));
    TestIfListOfEnum(typeof(DayOfWeek[]));
    TestIfListOfEnum(typeof(List<int>));
    TestIfListOfEnum(typeof(List<DayOfWeek>));
    TestIfListOfEnum(typeof(List<DayOfWeek>));
    TestIfListOfEnum(typeof(IEnumerable<DayOfWeek>));
}

void TestIfListOfEnum(Type type)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Object Type: \"{0}\", List of Enum: {1}", type, IsListOfEnum(type));
}

bool IsListOfEnum(Type type)
{
    var itemInfo = type.GetProperty("Item");
    return (itemInfo != null) ? itemInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum : false;
}
```

Here's the output from the code above:

```
Object Type: "System.Int32", List of Enum: False
Object Type: "System.DayOfWeek[]", List of Enum: False
Object Type: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]", List of Enum: False
Object Type: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DayOfWeek]", List of Enum: True
Object Type: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DayOfWeek]", List of Enum: True
Object Type: "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.DayOfWeek]", List of Enum: False
```

All of the output is exactly what I want except for the last example. It doesn't detect that `typeof(IEnumerable<DayOfWeek>)` is a collection of enum types.

Does anyone know how I can detect the enum types in this last example?

Comment: You're confusing [list/collection/sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26202545/3764814). It seems you want to test for a *sequence* of enums.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how I'm confused. Ideally, I would be able to detect the enum type in all these examples. That's what I want.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is a *sequence*. `ICollection<T>` is a collection. `IList<T>` is a list. It may be nitpicking but it's relevant to your question.

Comment: @Mephy: No, I think just collections of enums are enough. I don't need to worry about complex types that may contain enums.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: It's not nitpicking. But it doesn't seem to directly address the question at hand. I guess it gives me some areas to research if I don't get an answer.

Comment: Nope, it wasn't for addressing the question, but just the wording, that's why I said I was nitpicking ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test that, given a type, then it is of type `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is an `enum`, you can do the following.

First, a method to get the type(s) over which an enumerable enumerates:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetEnumerableTypes(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsInterface)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType
                && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            {
                yield return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            {
                yield return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

And then:

```
    public static bool IsEnumerableOfEnum(Type type)
    {
        return GetEnumerableTypes(type).Any(t => t.IsEnum);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, that appears to return false as well.

Comment: @JonathanWood - found & fixed.

Comment: @JonathanWood - updated to handle something like `public interface IBar : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> { }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the type of the `IEnumerable<T>` like this:

```
Type enumerableType = enumerable.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
```

then you can test to see if it's an enum by checking to see if that type is assignable to a variable of type `Enum`, the base class for enumerations:

```
typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(enumerableType)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple method:

```
public static bool TestIfSequenceOfEnum(Type type)
{
    return (type.IsInterface ? new[] { type } : type.GetInterfaces())
        .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        .Any(i => i.GetGenericArguments().First().IsEnum);
}
```

Basically, extract all interfaces implemented by the type, find all `IEnumerable<T>` and return `true` if any of these `T` is an enum. Remember a concrete class may implement `IEnumerable<T>` several times (with different `T`).

This works both if `type` is a class or if it's an interface.