# Using of IEqualityComparer<T> interface and EqualityComparer<T> class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, interface, equality

I am programming a circular linked list using [this article](http://navaneethkn.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/circular-linked-list/) as help.

In a function that searches in this list for a node with a given value

```
    public Node<T> Find(T item)
    {
        Node<T> node = FindNode(head, item);
        return node;
    }

    Node<T> FindNode(Node<T> node, T valueToCompare)
    {
        Node<T> result = null;
        if (comparer.Equals(node.Value, valueToCompare))
            result = node;
        else if (result == null && node.Next != head)
            result = FindNode(node.Next, valueToCompare);
        return result;
    }
```

an author uses an `IEqualityComparer<T> comparer` object, which is initialized with a property `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` in one of constructors. Can you please explain me an idea of using of these interface (`IEqualityComparer<T>`) and class (`EqualityComparer<T>`) here? I had read MSDN, but I didn't understand the principles of working and using of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEqualityComparer<in T>` is an interface that will handle equality comparisons for your collection. Your collection will delegate equiality comparisons to this interface. You may ask, why don't just call the `Equals` method?

Because there can be several kinds of possible comparisons. Let's take an easy example: are `"Abc"` and `"ABC"` equal? It depends. `"Abc".Equals("ABC") == false` but what if you want case insensitivity?

This is why your collection should *delegate* the equality comparisons to a different class. By composing classes, you'll respect the single responsibility principle: Your collection knows how to store the items, and the equality comparer knows if they're equal.

An example with sets:

```
var caseSensitive = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal) // The default anyway
{
    "Abc", "ABC"
};

var caseInsensitive = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    "Abc", "ABC"
};
```

The results will be:

```
caseSensitive.Count == 2
caseInsensitive.Count == 1

caseSensitive.Contains("aBc") == false
caseInsensitive.Contains("aBc") == true
```

Here you have two completely different set semantics using the same `HashSet` class.

Now, what's in an `IEqualityComparer<in T>`?

- `bool Equals(T x, T y);`: This method does just what you'd expect it to: it returns `true` if `x` should be considered equal to `y`. Just like the mathematical equality, it **must** be:

  - reflexive: `Equals(x, x) == true`
  - symmetric: `Equals(x, y) == Equals(y, x)`
  - transitive: if `Equals(x, y) && Equals(y, z)` then `Equals(x, z)`

- `int GetHashCode(T obj);` this one may be trickier to get right. For each `obj`, it should return a hash code wilth the following properties:

  - it should never change
  - if `Equals(x, y)` then `GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y)`
  - there should be as few collisions as possible

Note that this does not imply that if `GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y)` then `Equals(x, y)`. Two objects can have the same hash code but be inequal (there can be at most `0xFFFFFFFF` possible hash codes after all).

Collections often use the hash code to organize their items. For example, the `HashSet` will know that if two objects don't have the same hash code, they won't be equal and thus can organize its buckets accordingly. Hash codes are just an optimization.

Now, what's `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`? It's a conventient shortcut for an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that will use an object's own `Equals` and `GetHashCode` functions. This is a good default value as this is what you want to do most of the time: while strings can have multiple natural comparison types, this is not the case for integers for instance.

`EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will handle a couple special cases:

- if `T is IEquatable<T>`, it will use the `IEquatable<T>` interface
- if `T is Nullable<U>` and `U is IEquatable<U>` it will handle the case properly
- it will optimize for a couple special cases: `byte[]` and int-basd `Enum`.

Comment: Thank you again! Your answers are delightful.

Comment: You're welcome, I had this one ready since your last post was closed.

Comment: Anyway, it was that I wanted to see. Very clear explanations. Maybe you can advice some interesting resources? I only read Troelsen's book now, but perhaps another stuff is worth reading as well?

Comment: @Mstislav Sorry, I can't recommend a book myself since I've only read books that focus on narrow scopes. You may want to take a look at Jon Skeet's *C# in depth* which is considered a good reference, but I haven't read it myself so I can't comment further.